# yum upgrade does not save old file

Tags: rpm, yum, centos7

I have two file mark with the directive %config:

1- When I do: yum erase my_rpm the files are saved but

2- When I do: yum upgrade my_rpm the files are overwritten

How can I save my files when I use yum upgrade.

Update info:

After install my rpm I edit and save the files marked with the config directive. Then I do yum upgrade my_rpm and the files are not saved neither overwritten.

e.g.

```
file content before install: value=1
file content after install(edited): value=2
file content after upgrade: value=2
```

I would expect:

```
file content before install: value=1
file content after install(edited): value=2
after upgrade two files:
      1. file saved with value=2
      2. new file with value=1
```

When I do: yum erase the files are saved

Update 2:

After re-read the rpm/spec documentation, upgrade was work fine.
if the file marked with config in the rpm new and rpm old are equals and the changes are in my local the upgrade will do a merge.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the %config(noreplace) directive:

```
%config(noreplace) /path/to/config-file
```

Here is [a very helpful site](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html) on what that means when you upgrade.

Comment: could you be more precise? What happens with your files? Did you edit the file in your rpm or the one that was installed? is your configfile.rpmsave or configfile.rpmnew present? give more info please

Comment: best edit your question with all that extra information

Comment: if my answer helped you on the way, please consider accepting it so people see that the problem is solved

Comment: The webpage was very useful